# How to do not run some of Playwright tests in certain browsers?

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest, playwright

I have tests which are running in Chromium, Firefox and Webkit (mobile) browsers.

But several of these tests should not be executed in the mobile browser.

How can I set skipping such tests if Playwright executes tests in Webkit?

I tried to use the pytest annotations from here https://playwright.dev/python/docs/test-runners#examples but it doesn't work, all tests are executed as earlier.

```
import pytest
@pytest.mark.only_browser("firefox")
# @pytest.mark.skip_browser("webkit")
def test_selected(order):
    order.open()
    order.set_channel('XXX')
```

The command for executing is `pytest ./tests/Orders` (if it's important).

For executing in a few browsers I use the fixture in `conftest.py`:

```
@fixture(scope="session",
         params=['chromium', 'firefox', 'mobile'],
         ids=['chromium', 'firefox', 'mobile'])
def pw(get_playwright, request):
    headless = True if request.config.getini('headless').casefold() == 'true' else False
    match request.param:
        case 'chromium':
            app = App(
                get_playwright.chromium.launch(headless=headless),
                {
                    'base_url': request.config.getini('base_url'),
                    'viewport': {"width": 1920, "height": 1080},
                },
            )
        case 'firefox':
            app = App(
                get_playwright.firefox.launch(headless=headless),
                {
                    'base_url': request.config.getini('base_url'),
                    'viewport': {"width": 1366, "height": 768}
                },
            )
        case 'mobile':
            app = App(
                get_playwright.webkit.launch(headless=headless),
                {
                    'base_url': request.config.getini('base_url'),
                    **get_playwright.devices['iPhone 14 Pro Max landscape']
                },
            )
        case _: assert False, 'Wrong browser'

    yield app
    app.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Conditionally skip`, this can skip certain tests based on the condition, e.g.:

**Single test:**

```
test('skip this test', async ({ page, browserName }) => {
  test.skip(browserName === 'firefox', 'Still working on it');
});
```

**Conditionally skip a group of tests:**

For example, you can run a group of tests just in Chromium by passing a callback.

```
    test.describe('chromium only', () => {
      test.skip(({ browserName }) => browserName !== 'chromium', 'Chromium only!');
    
      test.beforeAll(async () => {
        // This hook is only run in Chromium.
      });
    
      test('test 1', async ({ page }) => {
        // This test is only run in Chromium.
      });
    
      test('test 2', async ({ page }) => {
        // This test is only run in Chromium.
      });
    });
```

Comment: OP is using Python, not JS